# Right way to write multiple options search query

Tags: mysql

Belove is My search Query which works fine if I want any one of the passed value search , but what if i want exact match for particular value ?

I can use `AND` operator but that will increase number of lines ,for example how can i write query if I want `particular location` match ,pls can any one help me out with better search query 
[image]

```
            $sql = "SELECT * ";
            $sql .= "FROM js_projects WHERE ";
            $sql .= "jsp_title LIKE '%" . $valToSearch . "%' ";
            $sql .= "OR jsp_nature LIKE '%" . $nature . "%' ";
            $sql .= "OR jsp_etype LIKE '%" . $etype . "%' ";
            $sql .= "OR jsp_location LIKE '%" . $location . "%' ";
            $sql .= "OR jsp_date LIKE '%" . $jobdate . "%' ";
```

**Edit**

Suppose I have value for

1. valtosearch,location,jobdate,etype and I want exact match for all this values ,
2. or I can have any two of these values and I want exact match for them ,
3. or I can have any one of these values and I want exact match for that .

So how can I write query for all these possiblities?

Comment: Can you provide some sample data and the expected output from that?

Comment: Use parantheses and a single AND .. "(jsp_location LIKE '%" . $location . "%' ) AND ("jsp_title LIKE '%" . $valToSearch . "%' OR jsp_nature LIKE '%" . $nature . "%' " etc. ....

Comment: @PrerakSola I have added possibilities in question for which i want output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like this. This will work fine

```
$condition=($location!=''?" AND jsp_location LIKE '%".$location."%":"");
$condition.=($jobdate!=''?" AND jsp_date LIKE '%".$jobDate."%":"");
$sql = "SELECT * FROM js_projects WHERE jsp_title LIKE '%".$valueToSearch."%' ".$condition;
```